# Chrome extention how to access object of target page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am working with chrome extension to make a small tool.

In the target webpage has this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var ico = new ICOTransaction();
})
```

So, how can I access ico object via injected scripts of chrome extension. Note that I only access variables which not in Jquery document ready event. All variables inside ready callback function are showed "undefined"